# Conveter RGB to HEX code in android

Tags: android, hex, rgb

i want to convert RGB color to HEX code so below is my code

```
ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog(getActivity(), initialColor, new ColorPickerDialog.OnColorSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onColorSelected(int color) {

                    String rgbString = "R: " + Color.red(color) + " B: " + Color.blue(color) + " G: " + Color.green(color);
                    int[] c={Color.red(color),Color.green(color),Color.blue(color)};
                    int sd=getHexColor(c);
                    System.out.println("HEx "+sd);
                }

            });
            colorPickerDialog.show();
```

**getHexColor function**

```
public     int getHexColor(int[] color) {
    return android.graphics.Color.rgb(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
}
```

When i run above code it gave me hex code like below

```
   -16569089  but i want like this   #23ab34
```

any idea how can i solve this problem?your all suggestion are appreciable.

Comment: you can use String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);

Comment: Darshil Shah :Working

Comment: please accept the answer so It will help others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android color value contains alpha value. ARGB

you can convert color.

```
int intColor = -16569089;
String hex = Integer.toHexString(intColor);

//prints ff032cff , A:ff, R:3, G:2c, B: ff
System.out.println(hex);

// remove alpha channel
int intColorRGB = intColor & 0x00ffffff;
String hex2 = Integer.toHexString(intColorRGB);

// prints 32cff, ignore leading 0 (int value)       
System.out.println(hex2);
```